# Add import routing for model routing page page not found

Tags: angular

I have project who whork find and  i want add a lot of CRUD page sow  globaly follow this example [Angular 13 CRUD Example with Web API](https://www.tutsmake.com/angular-13-crud-example-with-web-api/) and done search replace but when i do the routing i go page 404

```js
import { ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { CreateComponent } from '../user/create/create.component';
import { EditComponent } from '../user/edit/edit.component';
import { IndexComponent } from '../user/index/index.component';
import { ViewComponent } from '../user/view/view.component';

   
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'user', redirectTo: 'user/index', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'user/index', component: IndexComponent },
  { path: 'user/:userId/view', component: ViewComponent },
  { path: 'user/create', component: CreateComponent },
  { path: 'user/:userId/edit', component: EditComponent } 
];
   

export const userRoutingModule: ModuleWithProviders<any> = RouterModule.forChild(routes);
```

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeTableComponent } from './home-table/home-table.component';
import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
import { userRoutingModule } from './router/userRouting';

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '',   redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' }, // redirect to `first-component`
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent },  // Wildcard route for a 404 page
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes),userRoutingModule],
  exports: [RouterModule],
  declarations: [
  ],  
  providers: [  
  ], 
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

'home' address work but all others address don't work .
I try to add all path in maters router, change forrroot to forchild.

Comment: Where are your `router-outlet` ?

Comment: in app component and there are only that

Comment: You should add another one in the component's that gets loaded in the first router outlet. Then whachout for the `activatedRoute`

Comment: Just a hint: I see you are having all of your pages in a single module. This increases the load time and bundle size massively. Try using [lazy loading](https://angular.io/guide/lazy-loading-ngmodules#create-a-feature-module-with-routing). It essentially means a seperate module for each page where you only `import` the modules you actually need. `ng g module login --module account --route login`. This will prevent the download of javascript bundles that aren't needed.

Answer (score 0):

I find my problem, had to change the import order

```
imports: [userRoutingModule,RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
```